# angularJS, UI is not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, angular-material

Here is a simple example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQqxaj

In this example, I would like, if the "Cancel" button is clicked, the two button at the bottom to hide.

The problem is that, UI (ng-show) doesn't update, even after the inputFocused is set to false.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-input-container>
      <label> New Comment </label>
      <textarea ng-model="newCommentContent" ng-focus="isInputFocused = true"> </textarea>
    </md-input-container>
    <div ng-show="isInputFocused">
      <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Post</md-button>
      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="cancelNewComment()">Cancel</md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS

```
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.newCommentContent = '';
    $scope.isInputFocused = false;

    $scope.cancelNewComment = function() {
      $('input').blur(); // be sure input is not focused
      isInputFocused = false;
    };
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

short answer: I would suggest to use **ControllerAs** syntax. [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXxEEo?editors=1010) the solution.

```
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MyController', function() {
    this.newCommentContent = '';

    this.cancelNewComment = function() {
       this.newCommentContent = '';
   };
});
```

long answer: when you use old $scope syntax you never know which scope you are using right now. Material design directives and other directives can create their scopes and you will loose the data link.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make my button to hide when I click on "Cancel"

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are assigning an undefined variable not scope variable.

There is no need to use jQuery to blur the element...as soon as you click outside the textarea it will be blurred by browser

```
$scope.cancelNewComment = function() {
  // `isInputFocused` is undefined and not in scope
  $scope.isInputFocused = false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but add $scope (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWezgp) doesn't make my button to hide when I click on "Cancel"

Comment: did you remove `$('input')`? You forgot to include jQuery.js and is throwing errors...look in your console

Comment: always check console when things don't so what is expected

Answer (score 0):

I just chcked and it works in ur code. Replace :

```
click="cancelNewComment()"
```

with

```
click="isInputFocused = false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating `$scope.isInputFocused` in your function; you are updating an undeclared local variable `isInputFocused`.

Note that when clicking the cancel button it will always have the focus.

Change your function to:

```
$scope.cancelNewComment = function() {
  $scope.isInputFocused = false;
};
```